# Select data from other table base on our input

Tags: php, sql

This is my PHP file. I can't select the deadline from fyp1 where `fyp1.code = $tcode` (that is the input that we put). Please help.

```
<?php
include('inc/db.php');

if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

$tcode = $_POST['tcode'];
$idno = $_POST['idno'];
$sname = $_POST['sname'];
$datesub = date("Y-m-d");

$sql = "SELECT * FROM fyp1";
$select = mysql_query($sql,"SELECT deadline from fyp1 where fyp1.code = '$tcode'");

$name   = $_FILES['file']['name'];
$tmp_name = $_FILES['file']['tmp_name'];

if ($name && $tcode){
    $Location = "S.File/$name";
    move_uploaded_file($tmp_name, $Location);
    $query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO submission (taskcode,idno,name,file,time,dead) VALUES ('$tcode','$idno','$sname','$name','$datesub','$select')");
    header('Location:DisplayNews.php');
}else
    die("Please select a file");
}

?>
```

Comment: You should use the mysqli_* functions. The mysql extension for php is deprecated and removed from php 7.http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the php devdocs!

```
mixed mysql_query ( string $query [, resource $link_identifier = NULL ] )
```

You have to remove the following lines...

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM fyp1";
$select = mysql_query($sql,"SELECT deadline from fyp1 where fyp1.code = '$tcode'");
```

and replace them with a valid call:

```
$sql = "SELECT deadline ".
       "FROM fyp1 ".
       "WHERE code = '".mysql_real_escape_string($tcode)."' ");
```

Please never insert $_POST variables directly in SQL statements for security reasons!